# Android 9.0 ijkplayer setSpeed fail

Tags: java, android, ijkplayer

When I try to change video speed on Android 9.0, it dosen't work. Only fo 9.0 and only when set speed over 1.0. 
I just use mIjkVideoPlayer.setSpeed(1.0). 
It works on all other devices under 9.0. 
ijkplayer verson: 0.8.8
and this is the error log:

11-29 15:55:14.241 6747-6801/com.xiao.nicevieoplayer E/J4A: J4AC_android_media_AudioTrack__setSpeed 1.100000
11-29 15:55:14.241 6747-6801/com.xiao.nicevieoplayer D/AudioTrack: isSampleRateSpeedAllowed_l denied mAfLatency:80  mAfFrameCount:1920  mAfSampleRate:48000  sampleRate:44100  speed:1.100000 mFrameCount:3544 < minFrameCount:3888
11-29 15:55:14.241 6747-6801/com.xiao.nicevieoplayer W/AudioTrack: setPlaybackRate(1.100000, 1.000000) failed (buffer size)
11-29 15:55:14.242 6747-6801/com.xiao.nicevieoplayer W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: arguments out of range
11-29 15:55:14.242 6747-6801/com.xiao.nicevieoplayer W/System.err:     at android.media.AudioTrack.native_set_playback_params(Native Method)
11-29 15:55:14.242 6747-6801/com.xiao.nicevieoplayer W/System.err:     at android.media.AudioTrack.setPlaybackParams(AudioTrack.java:1902)
11-29 15:55:14.242 6747-6801/com.xiao.nicevieoplayer W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: arguments out of range
11-29 15:55:14.242 6747-6801/com.xiao.nicevieoplayer W/System.err:     at android.media.AudioTrack.native_set_playback_params(Native Method)
11-29 15:55:14.242 6747-6801/com.xiao.nicevieoplayer W/System.err:     at android.media.AudioTrack.setPlaybackParams(AudioTrack.java:1902)

Comment: I found the source code explanation Another possible cause is that the <code>AudioTrack</code> is streaming
     * (see {@link #MODE_STREAM}) and the
     * buffer size is too small. For speeds greater than 1.0f, the <code>AudioTrack</code> buffer
     * on configuration must be larger than the speed multiplied by the minimum size
     * {@link #getMinBufferSize(int, int, int)}) to allow proper playback.

Comment: but how to set the audiotrack buffer on configuration

Answer (score 0):

add this line when init ijkMediaPlayer:

```
ijkMediaPlayer.setOption(IjkMediaPlayer.OPT_CATEGORY_PLAYER, "soundtouch", 1);
```